# Cannot extract mysql's json column using Spring data JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using below SQL in mysql directly, I can get the items I want successfully, saying "['item1', 'item2']".

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(specific_job, '$.items') from t_job where id = 1;
```

But when I tried to use that in my Spring project with JPA, like below.

```
@Query(value = "select JSON_EXTRACT(specific_job, '$.items') from t_job where id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
String findJobItems(Long jobId);
```

It's very strange that, when calling this function, the query seems work, but only returns the first letter of the items, like "[".

Is this a bug of spring data JPA?
Or is there any better way to extract json fields in Spring data JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the items as varchar.

```
CAST(myColumn as CHAR(50))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. And I have found that I could cast items to varchar without the char length.    `CAST(myColumn as CHAR)`